Yarn Install Fails for Realm Package in VS Code Integrated Terminal but Works in macOS Terminal
I'm currently working on a project that uses React Native 0.63. When I clone the project directly onto the Desktop (e.g., ~/Desktop/app_clone) and run the command yarn install using the macOS terminal, everything works fine.
However, when I run yarn install using the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code, the installation fails specifically during the installation of the Realm package.
Why does this happen, and how can I resolve it?
Thank you.
/node_modules/realm: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build -j 8 ${npm_config_arch:+--target_arch=${npm_config_arch}}
/node_modules/realm
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.15.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@16.10.0 | darwin | arm64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "app/node_modules/realm/compiled/napi-v4_darwin_arm64/realm.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://static.realm.io/node-pre-gyp/napi-v4/realm-v10.1.2/realm-v10.1.2-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://static.realm.io/node-pre-gyp/napi-v4/realm-v10.1.2/realm-v10.1.2-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://static.realm.io/node-pre-gyp/napi-v4/realm-v10.1.2/realm-v10.1.2-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for realm@10.1.2 and node@16.10.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
I run the command on the mac terminal and it works fine.

Are they both the same (bash vs zhrc)? From the same location? Both have the same access permissions?

I don't know why, but my VS Code wasn't using the default Node version from the nvm package.

Probably configured path on the different terminals.
